# Good Alternative to PhantomJS for Integration ( E2E ) Testing

Tags: testing, phantomjs, integration, headless-browser, e2e-testing

I've been trying to use PhantomJS for headless browser testing, but there so many weird things going on. Any recommendations for alternatives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After dealing with this same dilemma myself, I can wholeheartedly recommend using your preferred Selenium webkit (mine is Chrome) in conjunction with [XVFB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xvfb).

XVFB allows you to heedlessly run a browser like Firefox, Chrome, etc. which basically eradicates all of the bugginess that inherently comes with using PhantomJS. While it’s definitely an awesome piece, it’s inner workings tend to have different interactions at times (I ran into issues for instance with not being able to TAB from one element to another like one can in any browser). If you are using Jenkins, there is an incredibly awesome Plugin which literally takes one click of a button. Otherwise, I’d definitely recommend checking [this](https://gist.github.com/addyosmani/5336747) out.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Please don't answer off-topic questions. StackOverflow is not the place for recommendation requests. The appropriate site would be [softwarerecs.se]. Also, please don't use two accounts to ask and answer the same question. You can self-answer your question with the same account.

Comment: While this does seem relevant to programming, I was just answering new queue questions. Thanks though, I'll check that Stack Exchange out.